# Accessing values in a dictionary containing AnyObject

Tags: swift

I have some data I stored into a dictionary which is defined as:

```
    let data = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
```

In this dictionary the value is always a string, but the value can be an array or integer or string. But when I try to access an item in a array in this dictionary, like:

```
    let item = data["key"][0]
```

It gives me this error:

> Cannot subscript value of type "AnyObject"

How should I access that item?

Comment: Did you try searching on that error message? This has been handled many times before already here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes I did, but I couldn't find anything that would fix this problem.

Comment: Well, let me put it this way. How is the compiler supposed to know that `data["key"]` is an array? You yourself have said it might be an integer or string, and you have typed it as an AnyObject, which is none of those.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the types.

Comment: That's probably the problem, how do I fix this?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler what this is. Or do a better job typing your dictionary. A dictionary of AnyObject is a Bad Smell from the get-go. You should probably stop and rearchitect your entire data model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler that you're expecting an array:

```
if let array = data["key"] as? [Int] {
    let item = array[0]
}
```

Without that, the compiler only knows that there MAY be an `AnyObject` in `data["key"]` (it might also be `nil`).